# What method to choose

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have 2*n pairs like `(a[i],b[i]) , i = 1..2*n` and I want to take n elements from vector a, and n elements from vector b such that sum of this elements take from a and b to be minimal and build `n` new pairs `(a[i],b[j]) with j<i and (j != i for any i,j = 1..2n)`. I think i need to use dynamic programming to solve this problem but I am not sure and how I can start.

Ex:
`For (3, 0) (7, 1) (2, 0) (5, 1) (6, 0) (4, 2)` I must choose `2(from pair 3) , 5(from pair 4), 4(6)` from a and `0(1), 1(2), 0(5)` from b with total sum 12 and  make new pairs like `(2(3),0(1)) (5(4),1(2)) (4(6),0(5))`.

Comment: Add a language tag to this post... I'm assuming C++ at this point, but I don't know for sure. Also could you show us what you've tried already

Comment: And maybe some code? Also the problem isn't really clear.